# Loading relation of new model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

I just want to get hasOne relation of New model.

Can I load it before I will save it.

I have `$user = new User(['order_id' => $order_id]);`

How can I get `$user->order;` without build new request?

Comment: You need to save this and then access the relationship.

Comment: You cant not load the relation of a model that does not exist (not saved yet)

Comment: you definitely can load it without saving it ... all that it cares about is the foreign key ... so just access it like you are attempting to (assuming that attribute is fillable in this example) .... also that is a Belongs To relationship

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out the model must be saved before retrieving any relations.

My usual approach for this is using [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```
// Create new model with data
$newModel = Model::create([
    'column' => $value
]);

// Use load to retrieve any relations
return $newModel->load('myRelationship');
```

Comment: it does not have to be saved (eloquent is not doing any check to see if the current model exists or not), this is a `belongsTo`, as long as that foreign key attribute has the value it will try to load the relationship as the key is for an existing record, not the new model